# OpenGl changing the unit of measure for coordinate system

Tags: c++, opengl, scaling, coordinate-systems, units-of-measurement

I'm learning OpenGL using the newest blue book, and I was hoping to get a point of clarification. The book says you can use any system of measurement for the coordinate system, however when doing 3d perspective programming, the world coordinates are +1/-1.

I guess where I am a little confused is lets say I want to use feet and inches for my world, and I want to build the interior of my house. Would I just use translates (x(feet), y(feet), z(feet)), extra, or is there some function to change you x,y world coordinates (i.e change the default from -1/+1 to lets say (-20/20). I know openGl converts everything unit left.

So i guess My biggest gap of knowledge is how to I model real world objects (lengths) to make sense in OPenGL?

Comment: would i do scaling like so and say 20/20 = 1 opengl unit and say i have something 5feet, would it be a length of 5/20 or .25 and just manually do all the scaling that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the author is referring to normalized coordinates (device coordinates) that appear after the perspective divide.

Typically when you actually manipulate objects in OpenGL you use standard world coordinates which are not limited to -1/+1.  These world coordinates can be anything you like and are translated into normalized coordinates by multiplying by the modelview and projection matrices then dividing by the homogeneous coordinate 'w'.

OpenGL will do all this for you (until you get into shaders) so don't really worry about normalized coordinates.

Comment: ok, so if i wanted to make a room that was 20x20 feet lets say, would i just set up my square to be something like grayFloorBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,4);
 grayFloorBatch.Vertex3f(-10.0f, -.56f,-10.0f);
 grayFloorBatch.Vertex3f(10.0f, -.56f,-10.0f);
 grayFloorBatch.Vertex3f(-10.0f, -.56f,10.0f);
 grayFloorBatch.Vertex3f(10.0f, -.56f,10.0f);
 grayFloorBatch.End(); Do you usually split your objects in half around the 0,0,0 or could you just build int he postive quadrant just use all 20s instead of 10s?

Comment: I've been playing around with the spear wold example if that helps any.

Comment: What you're doing looks fine in principle (I haven't checked your numbers).  Typically in order to make a good general purpose program you would define your geometry in object space (with a local origin) and use transformations (translations etc) to put in in the correct spot in world space.

Comment: so if i have something 20x20 that could be foot units, or centimeters, my choice right? However if its centimeters, that seems rather large, not to scale at all.

Comment: Yep, your choice.  I would hazard on the side of keeping your unit numbers small for both debugging and precision reasons.  Many games use meters or feet as their base unit.

Answer (score 2):

Well its all relative.  If you set 1 OpenGL unit to be 1 meter and then build everything perfectly to scale on that basis then you have the scale you want (ie 10 meters would be 10 openGL units and 1 millimeter would be 0.001 OpenGL units.

If, however, you were to then introduce a model that was designed such that 1 OpenGL unit = 1 foot then the object is going to end up being ~3 times too large.

Sure you can change between the various methods but by far the best way to do this is to re-scale your model before loading it into your engine.

Answer (score 1):

> …however when doing 3d perspective programming, the world coordinates are +1/-1.

Says who? Maybe you are referring to clip space, however this is just one special space in which all coordinates are after projection.

You world units may be anything. The relevant part is, how those are projected. Say you have a perspective projection of 90°FOV, near clip plane at 0.01, far clip plane at 10.0, quadratic aspect (for simplicity). Then your view volume into the world will resolve a rectangle with side lengths 0.01 and 0.01 distance close to the viewer, and stretch to 10.0 in the distant with the 0.02 side lengths. Reduce the FOV and the lateral lenghts shrink accordingly.

Nevertheless, coordinates in about the range 0.01 to 10. are projected into the +/-1 clip space.

So it's up to you to choose the projection limits to match your scene and units of choice.

Comment: I think clip space has in part to do with my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Normalized window coordinate range is always -1 to +1. But it  can be used as you wish.
Suppose we want a range -100 to +100 then divide actual coordinate with 100. In this case use
the function glVertex2f or glVertex3f only.
e.g. glVertex2f(10/100,10/100).